# Save Button in Message Protocol in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have been trying to update the parameters from `DetailViewModel` to `MainViewModel` via using message protocol in mvvmcross. The following code works if you want to update the properties on-the-fly; however, I am confused because I have `save` button which allows user to confirm his changes in the `DetailViewModel` before go back to `MainViewModel`.

How should I handle that scenario? Is there a way around to handle?

**MainViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;
private readonly MvxSubscriptionToken _token;

public MainViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {

    _messenger = messenger;
    _token = messenger.Subscribe<SelectedItemMessage>(OnMessageReceived);;
}

private void OnMessageReceived(SelectedItemMessage obj)
{
    Age = obj.Age;
    Category= obj.Category;
}
```

**DetailViewModel**

```
private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

public DetailViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger) {
    _messenger = messenger;
}

public void UpdateMethod() {
    var message = new SelectedItemMessage(this, SelectedItem); 
    _messenger.Publish(message, typeof(SelectedItemMessage));
}
```

**SelectedItemMessage**

```
public SelectedItemMessage(object sender, double age, int category) : base(sender)
    {
        Age = age;
        Category = category;
    }

    public double Age { get; set; }
    public int Category{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What code is behind the `Save` method?

Comment: @hotspring - What problem do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data should only get updated when the user does a `Save` action, call the `UpdateMethod` when your user presses it.

```
public void Save() {

    UpdateMethod();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Pilatus. when I am trying to change the `age`, I am getting `formatnumber exception`. In other words when I clear the value/number from the `textview` before I enter the new value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [ACR MvvmCross User Dialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs) library to show confirmation dialog and call `UpdateMethod` only if the user confirmed the action:

```
var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync("Pick a choice", "Pick Title");
if (result)
{
    UpdateMethod();
}
```

Make sure that you [Setup the library](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs#setup) correctly before using it